# A view with a Button child, if I set view's height to 0, the button does not disappear,why?

Tags: native-base

Here is the code, it is very simple:

```
render() {
    return (
     <View>
         <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        <View style={{height:0}}>
            <Button>
                <Text>this button should disappears</Text>
            </Button>
        </View>
        <View style={{height:400}}>
            <Text>other view</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
   );
}
```

And here is the output screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, because the height of the view is 0, so the button's container  is invisible, but why is the button still visible?

After some work, I found out that I have to set the 'other view' 's backgroundColor&height to overlap the button, like that:

```
<View style={{height:400,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
   <Text>other view</Text>
</View>
```

Now the button will be invisible.

It's so strange, just Button component, I have tried several other components, they are all ok, is it a bug of Button?

Thanks Wong Kim Hau for his reminding, the Button component is from 'native-base', not 'react native'

I'm using react-native v0.44.0, native-base 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

just use the default Button component from 'react-native', it work fine.

Comment: thanks for your reminding, the Button is from 'native-base',I have change the tag and the question description